# Measuring the time taken when shaking device

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application that measures the total time of a shake event. In other words, the timer starts when the shake event is started, and the timer stops when the shake event ends.

So my question is, if we hold two iTouches in a single hand and then shake both at the same time, will the shake event generate the same value on both iTouches?

This is my code:

```
-(void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.00025 target:self selector:@selector(showactivity) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
}
-(void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {  
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting different values as of now. So wanted to know if thats the case always.

Comment: Can you add some code as to how you're measuring the shakes?

Comment: Why are you doing such a small timer interval?  The shakes are not that accurate.

Comment: what would be a better interval?

Comment: and the problem is that , if we shake for a longer time, the timer is not stopping. It continues until we force quit the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just make an instance variable of type `NSDate` called `shakesBegan`, or whatever.  Then just call this in `motionBegan`:

```
-(void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {
        shakesBegan = [NSDate date];
    }
}

-(void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {  
        NSDate *shakesFinished = [NSDate date];
        NSTimeInterval shakeTime = [shakesFinished timeIntervalSinceDate:shakesBegan];
        NSLog(@"Shaken for %f seconds",shakeTime);
    }
}
```

The output should say something like `Shaken for 1.233242 seconds`. However, I don't have a device to test this so your mileage may vary.

---

The reason you're getting an error is because you must make `shakesBegan` an instance variable.  Like this in your interface:

```
@interface Something : UIViewController
{
    NSDate *shakesBegan;
}
@end
```

Comment: what is the "methodfinish" that you used there?

Comment: Oops, that should be `shakesFinished`.

Comment: But the thing is that, Its not recognizing "shakesBegan" in motionEnded. because its been declared in motionBegan. Thats the error thats popping up.

Comment: Is there a way where we can use the motionBegan and motionEnded and still get a good result for the shake feature?

Comment: Right now, the timer is starting when the shake starts but if I shake for a long time and stop, the time is not stopping. I have to force-quit the application. Can this be handled ?

Comment: @user: Well, to be honest, since this is a system-managed notification there's really nothing you can do other than removing this verification: `if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {` in `motionEnded`. Maybe it thinks the motion that finished isn't a shake.   If that doesn't work, then you'll have to implement your own motion detecting using Core Motion.